# Calculating $\int_{-\beta}^{\beta}\sqrt{\beta^2-x^2}\frac{\cos(\phi-\frac{3}{2}\arctan(\frac{\gamma+x}{\alpha}))}{(\alpha^2+(\gamma+x)^2)^{3/4}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I want to solve the following integral

\begin{align}
 \int_{-\beta}^{\beta}\sqrt{\beta^2-x^2}\frac{\cos\left(\phi-\frac{3}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{\gamma+x}{\alpha}\right)\right)}{\left(\alpha^2+(\gamma+x)^2\right)^{3/4}}\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}

with $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\phi\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Comment: Do you think a closed form exists? If so, then how come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral is expressible in terms of elliptic integrals.

For convenience the following will assume $\beta=1$, just a matter of renaming constants. Moreover, let $p=\alpha+i\gamma$, and observe that
$$
\frac{\cos\left(\phi-\frac{3}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{\gamma+x}{\alpha}\right)\right)}{\left(\alpha^2+(\gamma+x)^2\right)^{3/4}}=\Re\left(\frac{e^{i\phi}}{(p+ix)^{3/2}}\right)
$$
so what we actually have to handle is
$$
\begin{align}
I=&\int_{-1}^1\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{(p+ix)^{3/2}}dx
\\=&\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\left(\frac1{\Gamma(3/2)}\int_0^\infty t^{1/2}e^{-(p+ix)t}dt \right)dx
\\=&\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty t^{1/2}e^{-pt}dt\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-x^2}~e^{-itx}dx
\\=&2\sqrt\pi\int_0^\infty t^{-1/2}J_1(t)e^{-pt}dt
\\=&\frac{\pi  }{2 p^{3/2}}\, _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};2;-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
where the integral formula for Bessel functions
$$
\frac1\pi\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\cos(zx)dx=J_1(z)
$$
and the Laplace transformation
$$
\int_0^\infty t^{\nu } J_{\mu }(t)e^{-pt}dt=\frac{ \Gamma (\mu +\nu +1)}{2^\mu ~p^{\mu +\nu +1}\Gamma (\mu +1)}\, _2F_1\left(\frac{\mu +\nu +1}{2} ,\frac{\mu +\nu +2}{2}; \mu +1;-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)
$$
are used.

The rest is hypergeometry. By series representation it is easy to find
$$
\, _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};2;x\right)=-16\frac{d}{dx}\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4};1;x\right)
$$
Quadratic transformation shows that
$$
\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4};1;x\right)=\sqrt{\sqrt{x}+1}\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;\frac{4x}{(\sqrt{x}+1)^2}\right)
$$
Note that RHS reduces to elliptic integrals, whence
$$
\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4};1;-\frac1{p^2}\right)=\frac{2}{\pi } \sqrt{1-\frac{i}{p}} E\left(\frac{2}{1+i p}\right)
$$
Here
$$
E(m)=\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1-mx^2}}dx\\
K(m)=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-mx^2)}}
$$
and the branch cut is chosen by convention.

With the identity
$$
E'(m)=\frac{E(m)-K(m)}{2 m}
$$
we finally arrive at
$$
I=-8p^{3/2}\frac{d}{dp}\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{i}{p}} E\left(\frac{2}{1+i p}\right)\right)\\
=4 \sqrt{p-i} E\left(\frac{2}{1+i p}\right)-\frac{4 p}{\sqrt{p-i}} K\left(\frac{2}{1+i p}\right)
$$
Now the original integral is
$$
\sqrt\beta~\Re(e^{i\phi}I\ |_{p\to(\alpha+i\gamma)/\beta})
$$
One can further simplify the result by utilizing elliptic integral identities for complex arguments, but I am not really fond of doing so.

Comment: Excellent work!

Answer (score 4):

---

Define the function $\mathcal{I}:\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{3}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by the definite integral

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\phi\right)}:=\int_{-\beta}^{\beta}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{\beta^{2}-x^{2}}\cos{\left(\phi-\frac32\arctan{\left(\frac{\gamma+x}{\alpha}\right)}\right)}}{\left[\alpha^{2}+\left(\gamma+x\right)^{2}\right]^{3/4}}.$$

At first I was  hopeful this integral could be reduced to elliptic integrals, but alas it appears to be [hyper-elliptic](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Hyper-elliptic_integral). Here's what I found....

---

Suppose $\alpha>0\land\beta>0\land\gamma>0$. Without loss of generality, we may assume $0\le\phi<2\pi$.

Set $a:=\frac{\gamma-\beta}{\alpha}\land b:=\frac{\gamma+\beta}{\alpha}$, and note that $b>0\land b>a$. We can clean up $\mathcal{I}$ by rewriting it as

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\phi\right)}
&=\int_{-\beta}^{\beta}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{\beta^{2}-x^{2}}\cos{\left(\phi-\frac32\arctan{\left(\frac{\gamma+x}{\alpha}\right)}\right)}}{\left[\alpha^{2}+\left(\gamma+x\right)^{2}\right]^{3/4}}\\
&=\int_{\frac{\gamma-\beta}{\alpha}}^{\frac{\gamma+\beta}{\alpha}}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\alpha\sqrt{\left(\beta+\gamma-y\alpha\right)\left(\beta-\gamma+y\alpha\right)}\cos{\left(\phi-\frac32\arctan{\left(y\right)}\right)}}{\left(\alpha^{2}+\alpha^{2}y^{2}\right)^{3/4}};~~~\small{\left[\frac{\gamma+x}{\alpha}=y\right]}\\
&=\int_{\frac{\gamma-\beta}{\alpha}}^{\frac{\gamma+\beta}{\alpha}}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}\sqrt{\left(\frac{\gamma+\beta}{\alpha}-y\right)\left(y-\frac{\gamma-\beta}{\alpha}\right)}\cos{\left(\phi-\frac32\arctan{\left(y\right)}\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\\
&=\sqrt{\alpha}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\cos{\left(\phi-\frac32\arctan{\left(y\right)}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

Making use of trigonometric identities such as the angle difference formula

$$\cos{\left(z-w\right)}=\cos{\left(z\right)}\cos{\left(w\right)}+\sin{\left(z\right)}\sin{\left(w\right)},$$

the multiple-angle formulas

$$\sin{\left(2z\right)}=2\sin{\left(z\right)}\cos{\left(z\right)},$$

$$\cos{\left(2z\right)}=\cos^{2}{\left(z\right)}-\sin^{2}{\left(z\right)},$$

$$\sin{\left(3z\right)}=3\sin{\left(z\right)}-4\sin^{3}{\left(z\right)},$$

$$\cos{\left(3z\right)}=4\cos^{3}{\left(z\right)}-3\cos{\left(z\right)},$$

the power-reduction formulas

$$\sin^{2}{\left(z\right)}=\frac{1-\cos{\left(2z\right)}}{2},$$

$$\cos^{2}{\left(z\right)}=\frac{1+\cos{\left(2z\right)}}{2},$$

the half-angle formulas

$$\cos{\left(\frac{\tau}{2}\right)}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos{\left(\tau\right)}}{2}};~~~\small{-\pi<\tau<\pi},$$

$$\sin{\left(\frac{\tau}{2}\right)}=\frac{\sin{\left(\tau\right)}}{2\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos{\left(\tau\right)}}{2}}};~~~\small{-\pi<\tau<\pi},$$

and the composition formulas

$$\sin{\left(\arctan{\left(y\right)}\right)}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^{2}}},$$

$$\cos{\left(\arctan{\left(y\right)}\right)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^{2}}},$$

we can rewrite the integrand of $\mathcal{I}$ in algebraic form as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathcal{I}{\left(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\phi\right)}}{\sqrt{\alpha}}
&=\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\cos{\left(\phi-\frac32\arctan{\left(y\right)}\right)}\\
&=\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\cos{\left(\phi-\frac32\tau\right)};~~~\small{\tau:=\arctan{\left(y\right)}\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\\
&=\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\left[\cos{\left(\phi\right)}\cos{\left(\frac32\tau\right)}+\sin{\left(\phi\right)}\sin{\left(\frac32\tau\right)}\right]\\
&=\cos{\left(\phi\right)}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\cos{\left(\frac32\tau\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\sin{\left(\phi\right)}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\sin{\left(\frac32\tau\right)}\\
&=\cos{\left(\phi\right)}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\left[4\cos^{3}{\left(\frac{\tau}{2}\right)}-3\cos{\left(\frac{\tau}{2}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\sin{\left(\phi\right)}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\left[3\sin{\left(\frac{\tau}{2}\right)}-4\sin^{3}{\left(\frac{\tau}{2}\right)}\right]\\
&=\cos{\left(\phi\right)}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\left[4\cos^{2}{\left(\frac{\tau}{2}\right)}-3\right]\cos{\left(\frac{\tau}{2}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\sin{\left(\phi\right)}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\left[3-4\sin^{2}{\left(\frac{\tau}{2}\right)}\right]\sin{\left(\frac{\tau}{2}\right)}\\
&=\cos{\left(\phi\right)}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\left[2\cos{\left(\tau\right)}-1\right]\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos{\left(\tau\right)}}{2}}\\
&~~~~~+\sin{\left(\phi\right)}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\left[2\cos{\left(\tau\right)}+1\right]\frac{\sin{\left(\tau\right)}}{2\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos{\left(\tau\right)}}{2}}}\\
&=\frac{\cos{\left(\phi\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\left[2\cos{\left(\tau\right)}-1\right]\sqrt{1+\cos{\left(\tau\right)}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\sin{\left(\phi\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\left[2\cos{\left(\tau\right)}+1\right]\frac{\sin{\left(\tau\right)}}{\sqrt{1+\cos{\left(\tau\right)}}}\\
&=\frac{\cos{\left(\phi\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\left[2\cos{\left(\tau\right)}-1\right]\sqrt{1+\cos{\left(\tau\right)}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\sin{\left(\phi\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\cdot\frac{\left[2\cos{\left(\tau\right)}+1\right]\left[1-\cos{\left(\tau\right)}\right]\sqrt{1+\cos{\left(\tau\right)}}}{\tan{\left(\tau\right)}\cos{\left(\tau\right)}}\\
&=\frac{\cos{\left(\phi\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\cdot\frac{2-\sec{\left(\tau\right)}}{\sec{\left(\tau\right)}}\sqrt{1+\cos{\left(\tau\right)}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\sin{\left(\phi\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\cdot\frac{\tan^{2}{\left(\tau\right)}-1+\sec{\left(\tau\right)}}{\tan{\left(\tau\right)}\sec{\left(\tau\right)}}\sqrt{1+\cos{\left(\tau\right)}}\\
&=\frac{\cos{\left(\phi\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\cdot\frac{2-\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}{\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\sin{\left(\phi\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{3/4}}\cdot\frac{y^{2}-1+\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}{y\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}}\\
&=\frac{\cos{\left(\phi\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2-\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\sin{\left(\phi\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{y^{2}-1+\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}{y\left(1+y^{2}\right)\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

Transforming the integrals using the Euler substitution

$$\sqrt{1+y^{2}}=y+t\implies y=\frac{1-t^{2}}{2t},$$

we find

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathcal{I}{\left(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\phi\right)}}{\sqrt{\alpha}}
&=\frac{\cos{\left(\phi\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2-\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\sin{\left(\phi\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{y^{2}-1+\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}{y\left(1+y^{2}\right)\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}\sqrt{\left(b-y\right)\left(y-a\right)}\\
&=\frac{\cos{\left(\phi\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a}^{\sqrt{1+b^{2}}-b}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{(-1)(1+t^{2})}{2t^{2}}\cdot\frac{2-\left(\frac{1+t^{2}}{2t}\right)}{\left(\frac{1+t^{2}}{2t}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{1+t^{2}}{2t}\right)}\\
&~~~~~\times\sqrt{1+\frac{1+t^{2}}{2t}}\sqrt{\left(b-\frac{1-t^{2}}{2t}\right)\left(\frac{1-t^{2}}{2t}-a\right)};~~~\small{\left[y=\frac{1-t^{2}}{2t}\right]}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\sin{\left(\phi\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a}^{\sqrt{1+b^{2}}-b}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{(-1)(1+t^{2})}{2t^{2}}\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{1-t^{2}}{2t}\right)^{2}-1+\left(\frac{1+t^{2}}{2t}\right)}{\left(\frac{1-t^{2}}{2t}\right)\left(\frac{1+t^{2}}{2t}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{1+t^{2}}{2t}\right)}\\
&~~~~~\times\sqrt{1+\frac{1+t^{2}}{2t}}\sqrt{\left(b-\frac{1-t^{2}}{2t}\right)\left(\frac{1-t^{2}}{2t}-a\right)};~~~\small{\left[y=\frac{1-t^{2}}{2t}\right]}\\
&=\frac{\cos{\left(\phi\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{\sqrt{1+b^{2}}-b}^{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\cdot\frac{2(2t)^{2}-\left(\frac{1+t^{2}}{2t}\right)(2t)^{2}}{\left(\frac{1+t^{2}}{2t}\right)^{2}(2t)^{2}}\\
&~~~~~\times\sqrt{1+\frac{1+t^{2}}{2t}}\sqrt{\left(b-\frac{1-t^{2}}{2t}\right)\left(\frac{1-t^{2}}{2t}-a\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\sin{\left(\phi\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{\sqrt{1+b^{2}}-b}^{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{1-t^{2}}{2t}\right)^{2}(2t)^{2}-(2t)^{2}+\left(\frac{1+t^{2}}{2t}\right)(2t)^{2}}{\left(\frac{1-t^{2}}{2t}\right)\left(\frac{1+t^{2}}{2t}\right)^{2}(2t)^{2}}\\
&~~~~~\times\sqrt{1+\frac{1+t^{2}}{2t}}\sqrt{\left(b-\frac{1-t^{2}}{2t}\right)\left(\frac{1-t^{2}}{2t}-a\right)}\\
&=\frac{\cos{\left(\phi\right)}}{2}\int_{\sqrt{1+b^{2}}-b}^{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1+t\right)\left[3-\left(2-t\right)^{2}\right]}{t\left(1+t^{2}\right)^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\left(t^{2}+2bt-1\right)\left(1-2at-t^{2}\right)}{t}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\sin{\left(\phi\right)}}{2}\int_{\sqrt{1+b^{2}}-b}^{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1-t\right)\left[\left(2+t\right)^{2}-3\right]}{t\left(1+t^{2}\right)^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\left(t^{2}+2bt-1\right)\left(1-2at-t^{2}\right)}{t}}.\\
\end{align}$$

Setting $A:=\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a\land B:=\sqrt{1+b^{2}}-b$, we have $0<B<1\land B<A$, and then

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathcal{I}{\left(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\phi\right)}}{\sqrt{\alpha}}
&=\frac{\cos{\left(\phi\right)}}{2}\int_{\sqrt{1+b^{2}}-b}^{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1+t\right)\left[3-\left(2-t\right)^{2}\right]}{t\left(1+t^{2}\right)^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\left(t^{2}+2bt-1\right)\left(1-2at-t^{2}\right)}{t}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\sin{\left(\phi\right)}}{2}\int_{\sqrt{1+b^{2}}-b}^{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1-t\right)\left[\left(2+t\right)^{2}-3\right]}{t\left(1+t^{2}\right)^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\left(t^{2}+2bt-1\right)\left(1-2at-t^{2}\right)}{t}}\\
&=\frac{\cos{\left(\phi\right)}}{2}\int_{\sqrt{1+b^{2}}-b}^{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1+t\right)\left[3-\left(2-t\right)^{2}\right]}{t\left(1+t^{2}\right)^{2}}\\
&~~~~~\times\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a-t\right)\left(a+\sqrt{1+a^{2}}+t\right)\left(t-\sqrt{1+b^{2}}+b\right)\left(t+b+\sqrt{1+b^{2}}\right)}{t}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\sin{\left(\phi\right)}}{2}\int_{\sqrt{1+b^{2}}-b}^{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1-t\right)\left[\left(2+t\right)^{2}-3\right]}{t\left(1+t^{2}\right)^{2}}\\
&~~~~~\times\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sqrt{1+a^{2}}-a-t\right)\left(a+\sqrt{1+a^{2}}+t\right)\left(t-\sqrt{1+b^{2}}+b\right)\left(t+b+\sqrt{1+b^{2}}\right)}{t}}\\
&=\cos{\left(\phi\right)}\int_{B}^{A}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1+t\right)\left[3-\left(2-t\right)^{2}\right]}{2t\left(1+t^{2}\right)^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\left(A-t\right)\left(t-B\right)\left(t+\frac{1}{A}\right)\left(t+\frac{1}{B}\right)}{t}}\\
&~~~~~+\sin{\left(\phi\right)}\int_{B}^{A}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1-t\right)\left[\left(2+t\right)^{2}-3\right]}{2t\left(1+t^{2}\right)^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\left(A-t\right)\left(t-B\right)\left(t+\frac{1}{A}\right)\left(t+\frac{1}{B}\right)}{t}}\\
&=\cos{\left(\phi\right)}\int_{B}^{A}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1+t\right)\left[3-\left(2-t\right)^{2}\right]\left(A-t\right)\left(t-B\right)\left(t+\frac{1}{A}\right)\left(t+\frac{1}{B}\right)}{2t\left(1+t^{2}\right)^{2}\sqrt{\left(A-t\right)\left(t-B\right)t\left(t+\frac{1}{A}\right)\left(t+\frac{1}{B}\right)}}\\
&~~~~~+\sin{\left(\phi\right)}\int_{B}^{A}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1-t\right)\left[\left(2+t\right)^{2}-3\right]\left(A-t\right)\left(t-B\right)\left(t+\frac{1}{A}\right)\left(t+\frac{1}{B}\right)}{2t\left(1+t^{2}\right)^{2}\sqrt{\left(A-t\right)\left(t-B\right)t\left(t+\frac{1}{A}\right)\left(t+\frac{1}{B}\right)}}.\\
\end{align}$$

Since $P{(t)}=\left(A-t\right)\left(t-B\right)t\left(t+\frac{1}{A}\right)\left(t+\frac{1}{B}\right)$ is a polynomial of degree $5$ without multiple roots, the final two integrals above are hyper-elliptic. As such, I don't believe it's possible to find a closed form expression in terms of well-known special functions.

---